# Product Pack and its product visiblity in sale order

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

How to show product pack's product in sales order line? Can product pack's product be editable and deletable for a particular customer in sale order line?

For example, I have product pack with multiple products in it and I have created a sale order for it and want to show all products in sale order of a product pack. But a customer wants to replace a product within product pack with another product. Is it possible make products editable and deletable for that customer only. That means I don't want to change a product pack's product globally but only for that customer.

May I get help on this issue?